# Joining 3 tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to join this 3 tables.

**delegations**

- delegations_id
- delegation

**delegates**

- delegates_id
- delegatesname
- delegations_id

**meals**

- delegates_id

---

```
$meals = Meal::join('delegates', 'delegates.delegates_id', '=', 'meals.delegates_id')
    ->join('delegates', 'delegates.delegations_id', '=', 'delegates.delegations_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

write following code in controller

```
use DB;
```

write following query inside of controller function

```
  $meals=DB::select("SELECT delegations .*, delegates .*,  meals.*
    FROM delegations 
        JOIN delegates
            ON delegates.delegations_id = delegations.delegations_id
        JOIN meals
            ON meals.delegates_id = delegates.delegates_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do it "manually" if your using laravel? check on this reference [eloquent-relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)

in that case just define in models (these are concept examples, I cant be sure about your project structure):

Meal

```
function delegate(){
  $this->belongsTo(Delegate::class);
}
```

Delegate

```
function delegation(){
  $this->belongsTo(Delegate::class);
}


function meal(){
  $this->hasOne(Meal::class);
}
```

Delegation

```
 function delegates(){
      $this->hasMany(Delegate::class);
    }
```

and then you could just do:

```
$meals = Meal::all();  
foreach ($meals as $meal){
    $delegates = $meal->delegate;
    $delegation = $mealt->delegate->delegation;
}
```

you can use it on the controller o on blades and then you'll have all the info you need for instance $delegate->name, $delegation->id an so on

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by two ways:

1.- Raw querys

```
use DB;
public static function getRaw_data(){
  return DB::select("SELECT d1.*, d2.*, m.* 
                     FROM delegations d1, delegates d2, meals m 
                     WHERE d1.delegations_id = d2.delegations_id AND d2.delegates_id = m.delegates_id );
```

}

2.-

```
    use DB;
    public static function getRaw_data(){
            return DB::table('delegations')
                  ->join('delegates','delegations.delegations_id','=','delegates.delegations_id')
                  ->join('meals','delegates.delegates_id','=','meals.delegates_id')
                  ->select('delegations.*','delegates.*','meals.*')
                  ->get();
        }
```